# How do you programatically get the XPath to cursor position in Eclipse in the contentAssistProcessor?

Tags: xpath, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am creating a custom XML editor (TextEditor) in Eclipse and am implementing IContentAssistProcessor. In the computeContextInformation, how do I compute the xpath of the current location of my cursor?

Comment: What is your editor based on - TextEditor, XText, the WST XML editor?

Comment: It is a TextEditor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the XML Dom node of where my cursor is in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742478/how-do-i-get-the-xml-dom-node-of-where-my-cursor-is-in-eclipse)