# How do I get the XML Dom node of where my cursor is in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, pde, content-assist

How do I get the xml dom node and xpath to where my cursor is in an Eclipse custom XML editor that I am building. It is a textEditor. I am implementing IContentAssistProcessor thus far.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have anything that would do this.

Comment: @greg-449 the XPath-style path to the currently selected XML element is already displayed in Eclipse window's status bar. The basic xml editor in eclipse has this feature. If there is no way to get the xml DOM Node how does it calculate XPath-style path based on where the cursor is?

Comment: I believe the editor you are talking about is part of Eclipse WTP rather than the Eclipse core. What it shows is nowhere near a full XPath expression, it doesn't deal with uniquely identifying elements at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of the [cursor in the text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827797/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-an-eclipse-texteditor) and you can implement an XML reader that stores the [locations of the XML nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915422/get-line-number-from-xml-node-java) using the [SAX Locator](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Locator.html). For a mouse event, you could then scan the document and find the best matching node. I am not sure how performant this is but this is where I would start.

Comment: the XPath-style path to the currently selected XML element is already displayed in Eclipse window's status bar. The basic xml editor in eclipse has this feature. If there is no way to get the xml DOM Node how does it calculate XPath-style path based on where the cursor is?